# Android ActionBar height issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm having a strange issue with figuring out the height of the `ActionBar`. I have a couple of parts in my app where something is positioned right below the `ActionBar`, and I'm also using Chris Banes' library [actionbar-pulltorefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh).

I'll use the example from the pull to refresh library. I'm experiencing the exact same thing as the issue [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/issues/41), except I'm doing everything exactly how the guide says to with `Fragments`. It basically calculates the height of the `ActionBar` to be about half of what it should be. Also in a different part of the app, I'm positioning a `PopupWindow` below the `ActionBar`, so I call the `getHeight()` and use that position for my window, I get the same issue as with the pull to refresh library.

So that makes me think it's something to do with how the `ActionBar` height is measured, and it may possibly be a style issue.

But here's where it gets interesting. If I rotate the devices to landscape mode, it figures the height fine and puts everything where it should be from that point on, even if I rotate back to portrait. it's suddenly fixed until I restart the app and kill it from memory and start fresh again.

Anyone had anything similar happen?

NOTE: I'm using the appcompat library now, but I was using ActionBarSherlock before, as well as the basic ActionBar at some point, and all scenarios gave the same result.

**UPDATE 1:** I get the same results from the issues [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/issues/41), [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/issues/46), and [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/issues/73). However I'm doing everything the README says to do so I'm fairly confident it's something to do with how my device measures the `ActionBar` height.

**UPDATE 2:** I used the actionbar PullToRefresh library in another activity and it works fine, so it must be something to do with my main `Activity`.

Comment: The question is when you call `getHeight()`? As Pull to refresh library calls it, at a particular time. i.e when `View` is created. on a side note you are using a `view pager`?

Comment: I am using a `ViewPager` in some `Fragments`, but the issue exists everywhere within the parent `Activity`.

Comment: I call `getHeight()` as one of the first things in my `Activity` `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 14):

In order to make sure there aren't Views under your Action Bar, you can add a top margin to it in the XML.

```
<SomeView
    ...
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style

**UPDATE**: The following is added on. I decided to dive into the Android source code to see what the actual ActionBar heights are supposed to be. So, I looked in all the different types of values/dimens.xml to find `action_bar_default_height`. Below are the findings.

In [values/dimens.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml),

```
<!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">48dip</dimen>
```

In [values-land/dimens.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values-land/dimens.xml),

```
<!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">40dip</dimen>
```

In [values-sw600dp/dimens.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml),

```
<!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">56dip</dimen>
```

I also checked the following, but they don't overwrite this attribute:

```
values-large
values-sw380dp
values-sw600dp-land
values-sw720dp
values-w360dp
values-w600dp
values-w720dp
values-xlarge
```

When I get more time, I may look for the root of the problem, but until then you can add these three values in your different values folders (as a temp fix).

Comment: It seems that the issue is actionBarSize returns the wrong value. It's about half of what it should be.

Comment: Okay. Now here's the first answer I was going to put down (but couldn't find source): I remember somewhere in the Android docs it said that ActionBar is 50dp high in portrait and 44dp high in landscape (smartphone device). But, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks. That should work as a band-aid, and if that's the best I can do, then I guess that'll have to work.

Comment: I added the lines to the respective dimens.xml folders. Do I have to apply the dimensions using a theme also?

Comment: You don't need to do anything with themes. Now you can just add the following attribute to your XML view that is being covered by the ActionBar: `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_default_height"`

Answer (score 4):

> I call getHeight() as one of the first things in my Activity
>   onCreate().

This is what returns the wrong height, most likely `0`. `ActionBar` isn't ready to provide you details about itself at this point. It is in the process of getting created, along with the rest of the activity's View.

Try the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Don't call setContentView(int)

    // Inflate the layout file that 
    // you would have used with setContentView(R.layout.xml_file)
    View mContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.xml_file, null);

    // Add this Runnbale to mContentView's message queue
    mContentView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(Your_Activity.this, "ActionBar's height is " + 
                        getActionBar().getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    // Initialize widgets contained in R.layout.xml_file

    // Example
    Button b = (Button) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);

    ....        

    setContentview(mContentView);
}
```

This should give you the correct value for ActionBar's height.

As a proof of concept, comment out `mContentView.post(...);` and simply show the Toast. The Toast will most likely say `ActionBar's height is 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go tonight. Even if I don't call `getHeight()` in my code anywhere, the PullToRefresh library still gives me the results from the links.